# Difference in Converting bmp images to jpg using paint and OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a bmp image and when i converted the image to jpg image using OpenCV and Paint, the two jpeg images looks same but while doing comparison they are different, even the file sizes are different.

I take the image from this [link](http://samples.fileformat.info/format/bmp/sample/4cb74cda027a43f3b278c05c3770950f/MARBLES.BMP?AWSAccessKeyId=0V91BEFA7GM093MEVMG2&Signature=jNtyiOy9gdUr3NTJpHQM58YxWUI%3D&Expires=1494519540).

And Saved it on my PC, and then i used mspaint to edit this image and save it as jpeg, the file size of this image is 356kb.
And when i used OpenCV to load the original downloaded bmp image and then saved the image as jpg, then the file size is 408kb.

When i used Beyond Compare to compare these images, the result is as follow:
[image]

Can anyone please help me in understanding this.

**Why I Want this**

Actually one of my colleague is capturing images using a pc application for preparing a database of images, so he is capturing the image using key F3 (Shortcut for capturing image in that software) and then click on File -> Save As -> Change the Type of Image of to JPG and then rename it as 0001---9999.jpg and finally save the image.

The problem with this Software is that if we press the F3 and then Ctrl+S, it saves the file as bmp and with the name as time-stamp.
So what i told my friend that, just click F3 and Ctrl+S (so that he can take many pictures for database) and then i will write a python script which will convert all the bmp files into jpg and rename them from 0000-9999. And this part is completed but then i came to know about the problem i shared above.
The database will be used with OpenCV.

Please suggest the reasons for this.

Comment: You're aware that jpeg is a lossy format, and that different compression ratios will result in different images being output, right?

Comment: @beaker Yes i know it's losssy type of compression and i got your point. You mean to say that, Compression Ratio in MS Paint and OpenCV2 are different that's why i am getting different size of images.

Comment: So using the following line
cv2.imwrite(filename, image, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 100])
I can control the quality of JPEG image.
So if want my image to be save as the image produced using the PC application, i must know the Quality Ratio.
Can anyone tell me, how can i determine the Compression ratio of the PC Software.
I will do hit and trial for this.
Thanks

Comment: Apparently, yes. JPEG is lossy, and the implementation of "compression ratio" is not defined by the standard, but in any way a compressing application wants to implement it. No point comparing JPEG images pixel-wise.

Comment: Use PNG if you can - lossless and compresses better than BMP

Comment: BMP says *"Hello, imagine you are limited hardware from the 1990s, tell me what you see". JPEG says *"Hello, tell me what you can see really quickly in less than 10 words". PNG says "Tell me exactly what's there". So the question is... what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPEG compression is a lossy compression. The fact that you have different output sizes already suggests that you have different compression rates. Therefor you cannot expect identical results.

The standard does not specify any quantization precision.

The maths involved in the compression (like the discrete cosine transform) require several approximations. For example how many digits will you use for Pi? How will you approximate cosine?...

All those things may differ between different implementations so even if you have the same compression rate you are not guaranteed to get identical results.

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG (and the standards) if you are interested in more details.

So unless you run both images through the same software it is unlikely that you will get what you want. Even in the same software there might be differences.

Comment: Yeah, I think this was all said in the comments on the question.

Comment: @barny questions are answered with answers, not with comments. no reason to downvote...